Modelling of a Markov Chain via Subsequences
I'm running into an interesting problem, in that I've found out that for the Markov Chain I'm trying to model I can improve my optimization results if I model unique subsequences of the process. The reason for this is that for every state transition I have quite a lot of noise during the transition. Here's how I've modelled it:
Assume $X_t$ is a non-Markovian stochastic dynamical system and that $X_t \in S=\{1,2,3,4,5,...m\}$. I am developing an optimal decision policy at the subsequence level. That is, for a given state subsequence $\{s_{\tau}\}$, I define the following increasing sequence of optional stopping times $\{\tau_i\} = \inf \{t : t>\tau_{i-1} \wedge X_{t} = s_i \}$.
For example, given a state subsequence of $\{s_{\tau}\}=\{1, 2, 3\}$ and a sequence of states generated by my process $\{X_t\}=\{\textbf{1},4,5,4,5,\textbf{2},8,7,8,7,8,7,8,7,5,\textbf{3}\}$, the process generated these optional stopping times $\{\tau_i\}=\{1, 6, 16\}$ and we have that $\{X_1=1,X_6=2,X_{16}=3\}$ was the trajectory observed by the subsequence process.
As you can see from the example above, the transitions (4, 5) and (8,7) are quite noisy and "loopy" (forgive me for the term, I have no idea what is the proper terminology).
I was wondering if you have any ideas on how to improve the modelling, given that while I am interested in the "noisy/loopy" transitions, they add very little value to my overall system. And every transition has a "noisy/loopy" counterpart - that is, after observing the transition (1, 2) the highest probability outcome is for it to loop back to (2, 1), and back to (1, 2), until the process moves on to a different subspace in my state space.
I've so far gotten the best results by looking at subsequences of my process, and I've also tried compressing the loop information by augmenting my model's state space to include the loops. For instance, the sequence above would be transformed into different transitions - let's call them $T = \{S \times S \rightarrow \mathbb{M} \}$ where I map the transition (1, 2) to a new state in M, state A. Let's also call its counterpart (2, 1) as B.
I then create a map from $Z : \mathbb{M}\rightarrow\mathbb{M}$ that defines the counterpart of the transition: $Z(A) = B$. I can then create a new state space $\Omega : T \times \mathbb{N}$ where the 1st dimension is the entry transition and the 2nd dimension is how many times it looped into its counterpart before we exited the noisy region of my state space.
Questions:

Do you think that by modelling my process via these unique subsequences (and their respective probabilities) I have introduced problems to my probability space, given my $\omega$ does not allow for repetition of the same state?
If yes to the above, do you think the compression scheme might be a better way to go about it?

And if you could give me a pointer or two on modelling the above I'd be very appreciative.
